# GKE won't scale up because of mysterious unbound pvc's

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

The cluster logs say it won't scale because "pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims".  And they even give a pod.  When I look, that pod has it's pvc bound and looks fine.  I even checked all pvc's on the cluster.  They are all bound.

Looking at the cluster events it appears as though it looked for something to preempt, but found nothing.  Then magically was able to make everything work.

```
48m         Warning   FailedScheduling          pod/postgres-8670-0                               0/7 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/7 nodes are available: 7 No preemption victims found for incoming pod..
48m         Normal    NotTriggerScaleUp         pod/postgres-8670-0                               pod didn't trigger scale-up: 9 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
48m         Normal    Scheduled                 pod/postgres-8670-0                               Successfully assigned gw/postgres-8670-0 to gke-my-cluster-node-pool-7462b5a2-wkrz
48m         Normal    SuccessfulAttachVolume    pod/postgres-8670-0                               AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-ea8ab3e0-2ed5-40bd-8456-a0707a5f4b18"
48m         Normal    Pulled                    pod/postgres-8670-0                               ...
49m         Normal    Provisioning              persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-8670               External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "gateway/postgres-8670-0"
49m         Normal    ExternalProvisioning      persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-8670               waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "pd.csi.storage.gke.io" or manually created by system administrator
49m         Normal    Injected                  statefulset/postgres-8670                         Linkerd sidecar proxy injected
49m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate          statefulset/postgres-8670                         create Pod postgres-8670-0 in StatefulSet postgres-8670 successful
48m         Normal    ProvisioningSucceeded     persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-8670               Successfully provisioned volume pvc-ea8ab3e0-2ed5-40bd-8456-a0707a5f4b18
```

Also the storage class is standard...

```
(⎈|rosalyn:gateway)➜  ~ kc get sc standard
NAME                 PROVISIONER            RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE   ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
standard (default)   kubernetes.io/gce-pd   Delete          Immediate           true                   370d
```

I can't find a problem to fix other than it just won't scale up the nodes like it should.
Anyone have ideas on where to look?

EDIT:
I talked to GCP support and we dug in on this.  It turns out we are getting this error everytime we create a PV.  And that the creation and binding works just fine.  So still following up with them on that part.

But also while it causes the cluster to show an error on the UI saying it can't scale, it scales just fine.  I thought it wasn't because I created a new node group with a minimum number of nodes and it sat at 0.  Turns out min means the min it will scale down to, not min it will scale up to.

We will see if they can explain why the error occurs when the PV creation works.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logs and information you've provided, the primary reason given for not scaling up is "pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims". The autoscaler considers a pod unschedulable if it has unbound immediate PVCs. However, you've mentioned that the PVCs are in fact bounded which implies there might be  mismatches or configuration concerns.

There are a lot of points that needed to be checked like version of GKE since there are known issues with autoscaling for versions prior to 1.22.[1] Also consider if you are using dynamic volume provisioning, there can be delays between PVC creation and volume provisioning bound to the PVC. The pod referencing the PVC is considered unschedulable and might be one cause to present auto scaling. Lastly, double check the Cluster Autoscaler configuration and logs. It may be worth a second look for more symptoms.  Attached are some good reads that may be of help regarding your use case.[2][3]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler#known_issues

[2] https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/

[3] https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I just put an edit above based on some things learned while talking to GCP support.  It seems that despite is saying it can't scale.  It can.  It just didn't in a case where I thought it should, but they say that is expected.  The error itself seems to happen on every successful PV creation.  So we are still looking into that.  Your idea of a possible delay might be the cause though.  Cause it works in the end.